# Question on hadamard gate and cnot gate circuit tables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

I'm trying to solve this problem for homework:

> Now show that if the **CNOT** gate is applied in the Hadamard basis - i.e. apply the Hadamard gate to
>   the inputs and outputs of the **CNOT** gate - then the result is a **CNOT** gate with the control and target
>   qubit swapped.

So I've computed the truth table for $a/b$ with just a **CNOT** gate, but I'm not sure how to "apply the Hadamard gate". I know that applying Hadamard twice will leave the bit unchanged (verified this via matrix multiplication), but I'm stuck at this part:

Let's say $a$ and $b$ are qubits and both go through the Hadamard gate. Then they go into a **CNOT**, where $b$ is the control. If $a$ and $b$ started off at $|0 \rangle$, then their matrix version is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ $[ 1 1 ]$, but how do you apply that to a **CNOT**? Alternatively, if you leave them as kets, then how do you represent $H |0 \rangle $? It was straight forward just applying a **CNOT** since the states remain as either $|0 \rangle$ or $|1 \rangle$, but I don't understand what happens if you apply a Hadamard gate to a $0$ or $1$ qubit.

Comment: I am guessing you know the action of a Hadamard gate on the computational basis: H(|0>)=1/sqrt(2)(|0>+|1>) and H(|1>)=1/sqrt(2)(|0>-|1>). What state do you get when you apply a Hadamard to each qubit when the initial state is |00>? To compute the action of the CNOT gate, just use linearity the of quantum mechanics. For example CNOT(|00>+|11>)=CNOT|00>+CNOT|11>.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a calculation to get you started.$\def\ket#1{\lvert#1\rangle}$

- Define $\ket{h_j} = H\ket{j}$:
  $$\begin{align*}
  \ket{h_0} &= \tfrac1{\sqrt 2}\Bigl(\ket0 + \ket1\Bigr) \\
  \ket{h_1} &= \tfrac1{\sqrt 2}\Bigl(\ket0 - \ket1\Bigr)
  \end{align*}$$
- Compute (for example) $ \ket{h_0}\ket{h_1}$ by distributing the tensor product over the addition and subtraction:
  $$ \ket{h_0}\ket{h_1} = \tfrac12 \Big( \ket0\ket0 - \ket0\ket1 + \ket1\ket0 - \ket1\ket1 \Bigr) $$
- Compute the effect of **CNOT** on this state, distributing *it* over the additions and subtractions, applying it to each standard basis state in the expression:
  $$\begin{align*} \mathbf{CNOT}  \ket{h_0}\ket{h_1} &= \tfrac12\Bigl( \mathbf{CNOT} \ket0\ket0 - \mathbf{CNOT} \ket0\ket1  + \mathbf{CNOT} \ket1\ket0 - \mathbf{CNOT} \ket1\ket1 \Bigr) \\ &= \tfrac12\Bigl( \ket0\ket0 - \ket0\ket1  + \ket1\ket1 - \ket1\ket0 \Bigr) \\ &= \tfrac12\Bigl(  \ket0\ket0 - \ket0\ket1  -  \ket1\ket0 + \ket1\ket1 \Bigr)  \end{align*} $$
- Identify which state $\ket{h_j}\ket{h_k}$ (if any) this output represents. It may be useful to compute them ahead of time, for the purposes of comparison.

Alternatively, there is another way you can do it: compute $(H \otimes H) \mathbf{CNOT} (H \otimes H)^\dagger $ and determine what operation it performs on the *standard* basis — this is a more direct way of solving the problem.